# Constructor bean injection while having inheritance and abstract classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have the following class structure, where A, B and C are abstract classes. Whereas D-H are concrete classes.

[image]

D-H are `@Component`s.

Class A takes two services through constructor injection ServiceA and ServiceB.

Both ServiceA and ServiceB are defined as abstract. ServiceA has only one variant `z` and ServiceB has two variants `x` and `y`.

All these variants are `@Service`s.

All the classes inheriting B, i.e. D, E and F uses `z` and `x`

All the classes inheriting C, i.e. G and H uses `z` and `y`

Right now I am injecting `z` and `x` using `@Qualifier`s in the constructor of D, E and F, and similarly injecting `z` and `y` in the constructor of G and H.

I see a lot of duplication of `Qualifier("x")` in D, E and F. Can we reduce the code somehow so that the injection of `x` is done via ClassB itself instead of D, E and F?

Whenever somebody adds a new child class to B. They'll have to use `@Qualifier("x")` in their new class. Instead, if this variant(`x`) could have been passed from B itself. The new class does not need to do anything.

Comment: We could, of course. We could, for example, get the `ServiceB` with `@Qualifier("x")` programmatically in `ClassB`'s constructor. But there is a deeper problem here: why must everything that inherits from `ClassB` have the `x`-variant of `ServiceB`? This seems to violate the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The question seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why must everything that inherits from ClassB have the `x`-variant of `ServiceB`?: I know for sure that all the children of B will always be using `x`. Getting the bean programmatically doesn't look like an elegant solution to me.

Comment: Then why make the `x`-variant a bean? We could instantiate it in `B`'s constructor. Or we could define the `x`-variant as separate bean, and let `ClassB`'s constructor that new class as parameter.

Comment: `x` is being used by other parts of the code as well. Are you saying if A takes 100 beans then all of them needs to injected from the leaf classes? Can I not use inheritance to my advantage, so that this injection can be done just for one for a group of classes. Also, I am ready to make modifications in Class A as well. Can this be achieved by moving the services from the constructor of A to setters? Then can B and C have their setters injecting a specific bean?

Comment: Why not make the type of the `ServiceB` parameter in `ClassB`'s constructor be `x` instead of `ServiceB`?

Comment: @tgdavies Even if I do that. D, E, F will have to pass x in their constructor.

Comment: That seems like a very small overhead.

Comment: "*...if A takes 100 beans...*" - If any class takes 100 beans, then something is gone horribly, horribly wrong. --- I also presented the possibility to extract the `x`-variant of `ServiceB` in a distinct class (just like @tgdavies suggested). This seems like the simplest fix. On the topic of "just use inheritance"... there is the concept of [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), that might help (let whatever inherits from `ClassB` have an instance of `ClassB` and act as a proxy).